# Input == null java error

Tags: java, image, exception, io, null

Hi Ive been getting an annoying error Constantly it gives me the input == null error you get when an image cant be loaded. this is the code .

```
  package Graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class spritesheet {
    public String path;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int[] pixels;


        public spritesheet(String path){
            BufferedImage image = null;

            try {
                image =
                        ImageIO.read(spritesheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(image == null){
                return;
            }
            this.path = path;
            this.width = image.getWidth();
            this.height = image.getHeight();

            pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null ,0  , width);
        }           
        public int[][] getsprite(int x, int y, int[][] pixels){
            int i = 0;
            for(int xx = 0;xx< 7;x++){
                for(int yy = 0; yy< 7;yy++){
                    pixels[xx][yy] = this.pixels[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return pixels;
        }
    }
```

I have checked and the directory is perfectly correct.

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at Graphics.spritesheet.<init>(spritesheet.java:20)
    at Tile.Tile.<init>(Tile.java:9)
    at Tiles.Wall.<init>(Wall.java:8)
    at Tiles.tiles.<init>(tiles.java:6)
    at Core.core.<init>(core.java:27)
    at Core.core.main(core.java:140)
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? How is this code being called? What's `path`?

Comment: Path is the string that it uses it to find the area so if I make a new sprite sheet and set path to C://testfile.png then it will try to get it from there. that is the exact part that gives the error.

Comment: How are you calling `spritesheet`  constructor?

Comment: via    spritesheet s = new spritesheet(path);

Comment: here is the directory protected spritesheet s = new spritesheet("C:/Users/Lucas/workspace/Sprites/Blocks.png");

Answer (score 1):

Use `FileImageInputStream` to read your file

```
ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File(path)));
```

Since, your using an absolute path *(C:\test.png)* don't use `getresourceAsStream()` which is used to load a resource from your *classpath*. Secondly, you don't need to escape a forward slash in your path. Either use `C:/testfile.png` or `C:\\testfile.png`.

*Reference:*
[ImageIO#read(javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream%29)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Graphics.spritesheet.getsprite(spritesheet.java:39)
 at Tiles.Wall.<init>(Wall.java:9)
 at Tiles.tiles.<init>(tiles.java:6)
 at Core.core.<init>(core.java:27)
 at Core.core.main(core.java:140)
it just skips the image == null; and when it tries to search the file in the bottom part of the code it doesnt work

Comment: @user2551633 use ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File(path)));

Comment: thank you for all your help this has fixeed it. Turns out I made an error in my class

Comment: @user2551633 Glad you got things sorted out.

Comment: @user2551633 this may be funny, but try to copy the image in `C:/x/file.png`(not in C:/ exactly) and have a try